# How to find the amount of rows in a 2D array in C++ when the array is passed into a function

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, row

I am new to C++ and I have this function where I am adding a set int val to the ascii value of an inputted char array, and in order to do so I need to check if the size of the arr inputted is equal to the rows times cols. The issue is that since the arr is passed in as a pointer, I know I can't use the `sizeof()` command, so I am trying to come up with another solution in order figure out the number of rows and columns that arr has, so that I could compare it to the rows times columns.

```cpp
void add(char arr[][SIZE], int rows, int cols, int val){

    int arraySize = rows*cols;
    int rowSize = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (arr[rowSize][0] != '\0') rowSize++; 

    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++){
        int j = 0;
        while (arr[i][j] != '\0'){
            count++;
            j++;
        } 
        cout << j << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << count << endl << rowSize << endl << arraySize << endl;
}
```

My inputs in main are:

```cpp
    char arr[][SIZE] = {"bot  ","rot  ", "found", "low  "};
    add(arr,4,5,5);
```

The output I get from the above is:

```cpp
5bot
5rot
5found
5low
6=}-
2U
8}L9)
2
6=}-
2
68J}-
2
1
55
13
20
```

which makes no sense to me why the amount of rows is 13 and not 4. I have also tried:

```cpp
    char arr[][SIZE] = {{'A','3','@'},{'#','t','9'}};
    add(arr,2,3,5);
```

And the outputs of this are:

```cpp
3A3@
3#t9
6
2
6
```

which is what I expect to get.

I've also tried replacing this line:

```cpp
while (arr[rowSize][0] != '\0') rowSize++;
```

with

```cpp
while (arr[rowSize] != NULL) rowSize++;
```

but this will give me no output as it never stops running because I assume it is stuck in the while loop. Any guidance/explanation as to why this doesn't work and how to remedy it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forget that C-style arrays exist in the language - don't use them. Use `std::array` and `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You can't get *anything* back about array dimensions from a pointer. The information is simply not there.

Comment: There is no magically added `'\0'` nor `NULL` at the end of multidimensional array. If you need a sentinel value to find out size of multidimensional array, you have to add it yourself.

Comment: Could you elaborate on using std::array and std::vector? I can't change the function parameters.

Comment: If you can't change the parameters, you can't use them, but `std::array` and `std::vector` are smarter arrays. They both know their size and `std::vector`'s size can be changed at runtime, something that can't be done with `std::array` or a regular array. Generally you pick the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: Odds are very high that you are expected to use `rows` and `cols` to make sure you don't run off the end of the array.

Comment: In general you do not want to use raw arrays-of-arrays in C++. `std::vector<std::vector<...>>` would give you the size-information and be dynamic, but in your case it seems you actually just have a list of strings? In that case why not use `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: @supertooper87 I edited your original post to show the output you are getting without using an image. Pictures are usually a no-no on StackOverflow, because the links to them have a tendency to become dead links. If you pretend to edit your original question (by clicking `Edit`), you can see what I did. After viewing them, click `Cancel` to get rid of the Edit screen.

Answer (score 0):

###### How to get the size of a built-in array.

The trick is to use `std::size` at *the point where a built-in array is defined.*

`std::size` returns the number of elements in an array, not the number of bytes. Use the `sizeof` operator (at the point where an array is defined), if you need to know the number of bytes it occupies.

```cpp
char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
auto constexpr const SIZE = std::size(arr);
```

For a "two-dimensional array of char"—which is actually an "array of (arrays of char)"—you can use something like this:

```cpp
enum : std::size_t { COLS = 3 };
char arr[][COLS] = {{'a', 'b', 'c' }, {'d', 'e', 'f' }};

auto constexpr const ROWS = std::size(arr);
static_assert(ROWS == 2);

auto constexpr const SIZE = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char);
static_assert(SIZE == ROWS * COLS);
```

After that, you must pass both the array and its size to any function that uses the array.

The two arrays in your examples are quite different. The first array (I think) is intended to be an "array of pointers to const char." The string literals used in its initializer are stored in static memory. Each string literal does have a null character `'\0'`stored at its end, which is supplied by the compiler. The array is allocated on the stack, and pointers to the string literals are stored inside the array. Each element is the size of `const char*`. No characters are stored inside the array—null or otherwise—just pointers.

The second is an "array of (arrays of char)". This is not the same as "array of pointers to string literals", i.e., "array of pointers to const char." Unless you put the null character `'\0'` somewhere in the second array, it won't be there. The compiler does not put it there for you.

The program below demonstrates how to get the size of each kind of array, and how to pass it to a function. It is a complete program that runs, so you should be able to copy and paste, and test it without too much fiddling.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

enum : std::size_t { COLS = 3 };

void demo1_test(
    char arr[][COLS],
    std::size_t const n_rows,
    std::size_t const n_cols)
{
    std::size_t const SIZE{ n_rows * n_cols };
    std::cout
        << "ROWS  : " << n_rows << std::endl
        << "COLS  : " << n_cols << std::endl
        << "SIZE  : " << SIZE << std::endl
        << std::endl;
}
void demo1()
{
    std::cout << "Demo 1: array of (arrays of char) \n";
    char arr[][COLS] = { {'A','3','@'},{'#','t','9'} };

    auto constexpr const ROWS{ std::size(arr) };
    static_assert(ROWS == 2);

    auto constexpr const SIZE{ sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char) };
    static_assert(SIZE == ROWS * COLS);

    demo1_test(arr, ROWS, COLS);
}
void demo2_test(char const* arr[], std::size_t SIZE)
{
    std::cout << "SIZE : " << SIZE << std::endl;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
void demo2()
{
    std::cout << "Demo 2: array of pointer to const char \n";
    char const* arr[] = { "bot  ","rot  ", "found", "low  " };
    auto constexpr const SIZE{ std::size(arr) };
    demo2_test(arr, SIZE);
}
int main()
{
    demo1();
    demo2();
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Demo 1: array of (arrays of char)
ROWS  : 2
COLS  : 3
SIZE  : 6

Demo 2: array of pointer to const char
SIZE : 4
bot    rot    found  low
```

###### Conclusion

This answer demonstrates how to get what you asked about, without using `std::array` or `std::vector`. Nevertheless, in almost all use cases, it is better to use either one of those Standard Library containers instead of a built-in array.

Comment: Arguably you should never use `sizeof` for this purpose at all. There is `std::size`, which does the same thing, but doesn't break if applied to a pointer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the heads up. As I was typing, I kept having a lurking suspicion that something like this had been added to the Standard Library. Of course, when I searched for `std::element_size`, hoping it would take me where I needed to go, nothing came up. The best I could find was the "old-school" method given on the [CppReference page for sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof). I have now updated my answer to use `std::size`.